# Application based on Eclipse, started from Windows command line. How to give output on command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, cmd, stdout

We have a Java application based on Eclipse (main class implements IApplication) that is started from the Windows command line.  System.out is redirected to a file. How can I give some output on the command line where the application was initially started?

Comment: How did you redirect `System.out`? Via command line or in the Java program? If the latter, you can save the reference to another varaible so you can still write to it later.

Comment: Our application uses log4j. And the redirection of System.out appears to be via Java. In that class, I saved System.out statically into a variable and then used it to perform some output. But still all output goes into the file.

Comment: Maybe your class did not get called early enough to save `System.out`. I guess this could be a built-in feature of the Eclipse platform. Could you share the actual command line generated by Eclipse to run `eclipse.exe` or `javaw.exe`?

Comment: Mmh, I'm not sure if I can answer your question, billc.cn. We develop an application with Eclipse. Then I call an ant job on the command line. The result is an executable. If I call that, our implementation of IApplication.start() is called. What do you mean with "the actual command line"?

Comment: Normally what an eclipse executable does is to launch a new process (could be itself or `javaw`) with loads of arguments to host the JVM. Maybe the output redirection happened on that command line. If not, it must be done by eclipse itself. There's a `-consoleLog` command line argument you can try, but I suspect that logs all other junk to the console as well...